# How to call loss.backward in a torch training loop

Tags: python, torch

When i train my torch model using the

```
loss.backward()
```

function i get the error

> RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or
> directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed).
> Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call
> .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need
> to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access
> saved tensors after calling backward.

so i added

```
retain_graph=True
```

to the backward call but get another error with a user-friendly "good luck" at the end.

> RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has
> been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [512, 128]]
> is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace
> further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient.
> The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good
> luck!

So what can i do? Here is my epoch loop

```
for epoch in range(initial_num_epochs):
    
    hidden = initial_model.init_hidden(initial_batch_size)

    for i in range(0, initial_training_input_data.size(0) - initial_batch_size, initial_batch_size):
        inputs = initial_training_input_data[i:i + initial_batch_size]
        targets = initial_training_target_data[i:i + initial_batch_size]

        outputs, hidden = initial_model(inputs, hidden)
        loss = initial_criterion(outputs, targets)
        
        initial_optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        #loss.backward()        
        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        
        initial_optimizer.step()
        

    print(f'Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{initial_num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')
```

and the model looks like

```
class TextLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, num_layers=1):
        super(TextLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(hidden_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x, h):
        embedded = self.embedding(x)
        output, h = self.lstm(embedded, h)
        output = self.fc(output[:, -1, :])
        return output, h

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        return (torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size),
                torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size))
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a copy of '''hidden'''

```
for epoch in range(initial_num_epochs):
    
    hidden = initial_model.init_hidden(initial_batch_size)

    for i in range(0, initial_training_input_data.size(0) - initial_batch_size, initial_batch_size):
        inputs = initial_training_input_data[i:i + initial_batch_size]
        targets = initial_training_target_data[i:i + initial_batch_size]

        outputs, hidden = initial_model(inputs, hidden)
        
        hidden_copy = tuple(h.detach().clone() for h in hidden)
        
        loss = initial_criterion(outputs, targets)
        
        initial_optimizer.zero_grad()        
        loss.backward()        
        initial_optimizer.step()
        
        hidden = hidden_copy


    print(f'Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{initial_num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')
```